# Problemas con array PHP

Tags: php, array

Estimados.
Una consulta MySQL desde formulario genera el siguiente array php:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                [nomtag] => Flujometro Entrada PG TK 
                [Fecha] => 2016-01-01 
                [Valor] => 1234567 
                [medida] => m3 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                [nomtag] => Flujometro Entrada PG TK 
                [Fecha] => 2016-01-02 
                [Valor] => 2223124 
                [medida] => m3 
        ) 
) 

Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                [nomtag] => Entrada Recolectora PG TK 
                [Fecha] => 2016-01-01 
                [Valor] => 9876544 
                [medida] => m3 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                [nomtag] => Entrada Recolectora PG TK 
                [Fecha] => 2016-01-02 
                [Valor] => 9988112
                [medida] => m3 
        ) 
)
```

El resultado del array son dos array. Quiero sólo uno consecutivo array 0 1 2 3 y no dos arrays 0 1 y 0 1, de la siguiente forma:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                [nomtag] => Flujometro Entrada PG TK 
                [Fecha] => 2016-01-01 
                [Valor] => 1234567 
                [medida] => m3 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                [nomtag] => Flujometro Entrada PG TK 
                [Fecha] => 2016-01-02 
                [Valor] => 2223124 
                [medida] => m3
        )  
        [2] => Array ( 
                [nomtag] => Entrada Recolectora PG TK 
                [Fecha] => 2016-01-01 
                [Valor] => 9876544 
                [medida] => m3 
        ) 
        [3] => Array ( 
                [nomtag] => Entrada Recolectora PG TK 
                [Fecha] => 2016-01-02 
                [Valor] => 9988112 
                [medida] => m3 
        ) 
)
```

¿Es posible generar este último desde PHP tomando como base el primero?
Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Para unir 2 (o mas) `array` puedes usar [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php):

  ```
  $resultado = array_merge($array1, $array2);
  ```

  Aplicado a tu caso deberías hacerlo así:

  ```
  $resultado = array_merge($array[0], $array[1]);
  ```

  [Demo](http://rextester.com/CXLR77402)
- También puede usar [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.call-user-func-array.php) combinada con `array_merge` para "*aplanar*" el arreglo de entrada.

  ```
  $resultado = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$array);
  ```

  [Demo](http://rextester.com/MJMY92507)

Comment: Mi array envía el siguiente error en el compilador: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'Entrada' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in source_file.php on line 7 (utilizo PHP 7)

Comment: @CarlosCataldo, Tienes un error de sintaxis en la linea 7 del archivo _source_file.php_, aparentemente te falta cerrar un  `)`. Si quieres que de diga porque, necesito ver el código de esa linea y posiblemente todas las anteriores también.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Es la solución a mi problema respecto a la demo. Al parecer es otro mi problema, ya que tu solución solo arroja dos elementos. Mi problema debe estar en el resultado de la Query

Comment: @CarlosCataldo, [únete al chat para que veamos en detalle tu problema](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51733/problemas-con-array-php)